# Sybase: how do I create data that violates foreign key contraint

Tags: foreign-keys, sap-ase

I have an existing database with several rows that violate a foreign key constraint. How do I script this situation in a new database?

I believe some databases can create constraints that do not validate pre-existing data but cannot find this option in Sybase 12.

Sybase ASE 12.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a constraint doesn't validate against existing data.
So drop it, bob some garbage in and put it back...

Comment: That's what the destructions said , though it wasn't totally clear it might have just been check contraints. Thing is if you can't do it, how would you get into this state, db would have to be corrupt. It's something like alter table .. with no check in sql server. I've never done that either, may be it doesn't work. :)